# Modifying curves's arc in a path

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a simple box following a path created using the `CatmullRomCurve3`.

I'd like to have all the curves/edges to be more sharp. But I couldn't figure how to achieve this. Also not sure if I'm using the right type of curve for making paths.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>

<header>
 <style>
  body canvas{
   width: 100%,
   height: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
 </style>
</header>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var renderer, camera, scene, controls, box, path, speed = 0, 
 path_progress = 0, 
 axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
 tangent = new THREE.Vector3(),
 up = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);

function initRenderer(){
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 renderer.setClearColor(0x264d73, 1);
}

function initScene(){
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
}

function initCamera(){
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 camera.position.set(0, 40, 40);
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 scene.add(camera);
 
 //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , renderer.domElement );
}

function initLights(){
 var aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xD0D0D0, 0.5);
 scene.add(aLight);
}


////// Initializers ////////////////////////

function add_path(){
 path = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 )
 ]);

 path.closed = true;
 
 speed =  0.4 / path.getLength();
 
 var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00f0,
    });
 var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var splinePoints = path.getPoints(20);
 for (var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++) {
        geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);
    }
 var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
 
 add_box(splinePoints[0]);
}


function add_box( pos ){
 var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
 
 var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff,
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x001a33
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
   color: 0x80bfff
  })
 ];
 
 var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
 box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 
 box.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 box.position.copy( pos ); //// x,y,z //// 
 box.rotation.set( 0 , 0 , 0 ); 
 
 scene.add( box );
 
 camera.position.copy( box.position )
 camera.position.x += 20;
 camera.position.y +=  10;
 camera.lookAt(box.position);
 
 setInterval( function(){
  follow_path();
 }, 100);
}

function follow_path(){
 if( path !== null  ){
  if ( path_progress <= 1) {
   camera.lookAt(box.position);
   var pos = this.path.getPointAt( this.path_progress );
   box.position.copy( pos );
   tangent = this.path.getTangentAt( this.path_progress ).normalize();
   axis.crossVectors( this.up, this.tangent).normalize();
   var radians = Math.acos( this.up.dot(this.tangent) );
   box.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( this.axis, radians );
   path_progress += speed;
  }else{
   path_progress = 0;
  }
 }
}


///// Mouse events ////////

///// Main /////////
function main(){
 //console.log(" Initializing: ");
 initRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initScene();
 initCamera(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initLights();
 add_path();
 animate();
}

function animate(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render_all();
}

function render_all(){
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting the path `type = 'catmullrom'` and setting the `tension=0.1` solved the problem.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>

<header>
 <style>
  body canvas{
   width: 100%,
   height: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
 </style>
</header>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var renderer, camera, scene, controls, box, path, speed = 0, 
 path_progress = 0, 
 axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
 tangent = new THREE.Vector3(),
 up = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);

function initRenderer(){
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 renderer.setClearColor(0x264d73, 1);
}

function initScene(){
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
}

function initCamera(){
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 camera.position.set(0, 40, 40);
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 scene.add(camera);
 
 //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , renderer.domElement );
}

function initLights(){
 var aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xD0D0D0, 0.5);
 scene.add(aLight);
}


////// Initializers ////////////////////////

function add_path(){
 path = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 )
 ]);

 path.closed = true;
   path.type = "catmullrom";
 path.tension = 0.1;
 
 speed =  0.4 / path.getLength();
 
 var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00f0,
    });
 var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var splinePoints = path.getPoints(20);
 for (var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++) {
        geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);
    }
 var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
 
 add_box(splinePoints[0]);
}


function add_box( pos ){
 var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
 
 var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff,
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x001a33
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
   color: 0x80bfff
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
   color: 0x80bfff
  })
 ];
 
 var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
 box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 
 box.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 box.position.copy( pos ); //// x,y,z //// 
 box.rotation.set( 0 , 0 , 0 ); 
 
 scene.add( box );
 
 camera.position.copy( box.position )
 camera.position.x += 20;
 camera.position.y +=  10;
 camera.lookAt(box.position);
 
 setInterval( function(){
  follow_path();
 }, 100);
}

function follow_path(){
 if( path !== null  ){
  if ( path_progress <= 1) {
   camera.lookAt(box.position);
   var pos = this.path.getPointAt( this.path_progress );
   box.position.copy( pos );
   tangent = this.path.getTangentAt( this.path_progress ).normalize();
   axis.crossVectors( this.up, this.tangent).normalize();
   var radians = Math.acos( this.up.dot(this.tangent) );
   box.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( this.axis, radians );
   path_progress += speed;
  }else{
   path_progress = 0;
  }
 }
}


///// Mouse events ////////

///// Main /////////
function main(){
 //console.log(" Initializing: ");
 initRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initScene();
 initCamera(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initLights();
 add_path();
 animate();
}

function animate(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render_all();
}

function render_all(){
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```